# UICollectionView nested in UITableViewCell does not update using DispatchQueue after receiving new data

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` nested inside a `UITableViewCell`:

[image]

The number inside a collection view cell gets updated on a different view, so when I return back to this screen, I want to be able to refresh the view and the new numbers are reflected in their cells. I have a model called `topUserModel` in my collection view that I populate with data from my firebase database. When I pull down to refresh, the following function is run from inside my main table view:

```
@objc func refreshView(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //this is the row that the collection view is in
            if let index = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0) as? IndexPath {
                if let cell = self.homeTableView.cellForRow(at: index) as? TopUserContainerViewController {
                    cell.userCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
```

Which then runs my `awakeFromNib()` in collection view triggering:

```
func fetchTopUsers() {
    topUserModel.removeAll()
    let queryRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "ranking").queryLimited(toLast: 10)
    queryRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            let topUser = TopUser(dictionary: dictionary)
            self.topUserModel.append(topUser)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.userCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

note that the first thing I do is remove all data from the `topUserModel`. After storing the new data and appending it (see above), I can print out the value of that integer in that block of code to screen and it displays as the updated value.
However in my collection view (see below), if I were to print out the integer value at any point here (it's called `watchTime`), it still displays the old value even though the `topUserModel` has been wiped clean and new data has been added?:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "topUserCell", for: indexPath) as! TopUsersViewController

        if topUserModel.count > indexPath.row {
            //image stuff redacted
            Nuke.loadImage(
                with: ImageRequest(url: url).processed(with: _ProgressiveBlurImageProcessor()),
                options: options,
                into: cell.topUserImage
            )
            cell.topUserName.text = topUserModel[indexPath.row].username
            cell.topUserMinutes.text = "\(String(describing: topUserModel[indexPath.row].watchTime!))"
        }
        return cell
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Don't dequeue cell's anywhere other than in `cellForItemAt`. You need to ask your collection view for the relevant cell using `cellForTem` and reload the collectionview if it doesn't return `nil`

Comment: @Paulw11 your first comment makes sense, not sure why I added a dequeue outside of the `cellForItemAt` could you maybe elaborate a little more on the second part of your comment? Is this the function you were talking about using? `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: No, [`cellForItemAt`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618088-cellforitem?changes=_4) will give you the currently visible cell at the specified `indexPath` (if any).  You can use the returned value to update the visible cell.

Comment: @Paulw11 man Paul, sorry for my ignorance just having trouble understanding how I could update a cell given the return value of `cellForItemAt`. Quite new at ios. So I take this return `cell` and do what? Could you steer me to an example of what you're talking about? Thanks :)

Comment: Call `cell.userCollectionView.reloadData()` on it; assuming that the cell has access to the updated data it needs.

Comment: @Paulw11 isn't that what I'm doing in my first block of code though? I'm no longer using dequeue and now using `cellForRow` to identify the cell to call that `reloadData()`

Comment: No, in your first block of code you are calling `self.homeTableView.dequeueReusableCell` - This should be `cellForRow(at:)` - Sorry, I linked to the collection view equivalent before.

Comment: @Paulw11 yea, I have updated from the `dequeReusableCell` to `cellForRow` in my code, here I'll update the question code for you too. But essentially, I have set up what you're explaining I think.

Comment: Ok, but you are just reloading the collection view; you need to load the new data. `awakeFromNib` won't be called since you have an existing cell.  You should have an explicit method you can call to get the cell to fetch the data it needs. You would also have a problem when you scroll and cells were reused because `awakeFromNib` won't be called then either.

Comment: @Paulw11 lightbulb moment! Thanks for walking this through with me. I needed to add `cell.fetchUsers()` above the `DispatchQueue` :) I'll let you have an opportunity to set this as answer so I can credit you, but if you do not want to, I'll answer my own question in the morning. Seriously thanks again Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `dequeueReusableCell` anywhere but in `cellForRowAt`.

In order to get the currently displayed cell (if any) you use `cellForRowAt:`; this may return `nil` if the row isn't currently onscreen.

Once you have the cell you can reload it's data and refresh its collection view.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "topUserCell", for: indexPath) as! TopUsersViewController

        if topUserModel.count > indexPath.row {
            //image stuff redacted
            Nuke.loadImage(
                with: ImageRequest(url: url).processed(with: _ProgressiveBlurImageProcessor()),
                options: options,
                into: cell.topUserImage
            )
            cell.topUserName.text = topUserModel[indexPath.row].username
            cell.topUserMinutes.text = "\(String(describing: topUserModel[indexPath.row].watchTime!))"
        }
        return cell
    }
```

---

For example, if current indexPath is `(1, 0)`, but the cell is reused from an  indexPath `(100, 0)`. Because it is out of screen, and is reused to display new content.

```
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "topUserCell", for: indexPath) as! TopUsersViewController
```

---

```
if topUserModel.count > indexPath.row {
   // ... Update to new content
}

// If topUserModel.count <= indexPath.row, then the cell content is undefined.
// Use the original content of reuse cell. 
// Ex, it may be come from (100, 0), but current indexPath is (1, 0).
// ...

// You can add a property to the cell to observe the behavior.
if (cell.indexPath != indexPath) {
    // Ops .... 
}

// Update to current indexPath
cell.indexPath = indexPath
return cell
```